# How to access DataGrid column value

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have an autogenerated `DataGrid`and I want to retrieve the ID value. There is a `HyperLink button` on each row and I want to send the value of that row's ID to a `new page via query string`. The order of `ProductGrid` is as follows
`(HyperLinkButton,ID,Name,Details)`.

This is how I am binding the Grid:

```
public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ProductGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
  ProductGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And this is the HyperLink button click event where I tried retreiving the cell value but got null(commented)

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //string var = ProductGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(ProductGrid.SelectedItem).ToString();
  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home?", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Can somebody help me in finding out how can I send my cell value in a query string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowCommand event or try this way.

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
LinkButton lnkbtn= sender as LinkButton;
//getting particular row linkbutton
GridViewRow grow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
//getting userid of particular row
string prodid = ProductGrid.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
string prodname = grow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Comment: These classes are not available in silverlight :)

Comment: Is there a way I can split and extract values from `e.Result`? Because thats where the row is returned

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/a132f968-4471-4dcf-8239-32804e752b82/how-to-get-values-from-eresult-table?forum=silverlightwcf please refer this